# I work the whole day/ i work for the whole day

Tags: articles

If I wanted to say
"I work all day every week days"
Using "whole day" instead of "all day",
Should I say

"I work the whole day every week days?

Or

"I work whole days every week days"

Or

"I work a whole day every week days"

Or

"I work whole day every week days"

It will be helpful if there's an explanation why which is correct.
Thanks!

Comment: "...every week day" without the "s" on the end.

Comment: I work 24/5? ^-^

Answer (score 1):

I work the whole day every week day.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/all-or-whole

Answer (score 0):

In many countries, there are five working days -- usually from Monday to Friday (and are defined as such in official and legal usage even though many people work on weekends) -- and they are also called [weekdays](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/weekdays).

So, depending upon how long your working day usually lasts, you can say, for example:

> I work on weekdays from nine (a.m.) to six (p.m.)

Answer (score 0):

I think "I work whole days every week day" is perfectly natural, apart from repeating 'days'.

So maybe 'I work whole days Monday to Friday' would be okay too.

Even better, perhaps 'I work *full-time*' which just implies that you work a standard working week (Monday - Friday, ~9 to 6 as defined by Rompey).

full-time:

adjective

1.
occupying or using the whole of someone's available working time.
"a full-time job"